# Highlighting Angular project deprecated imports/parts

Tags: angular, updates, deprecated

**I googled a lot, but couldn't find any efficient solutions!**

How do you replace the deprecated part of an Angular application? Regardless of the size of the application, it would be really inefficient to check every file one by one to see if an import or module is deprecated.

Do you know any good practice to update an Angular project for example from Angular 5 to Angular 7?

And how do you know which parts are deprecated and needs to be replaced? 
For example, I know `import { Http } from '@angular/http'` needs to be replaced by `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'`  or `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'` in order to use `get` or `post`.

How do I find these deprecated parts and how do I know what should I use instead of them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TSLint will check all of that for you. Simply run `ng lint` and it will tell you what you wrote poorly, what is deprecated, and anything else that does not comply with your linter configuration.

Comment: my problem is that, it doesn't highlight the files which have deprecated parts, so I still need to open and check every one of them. I would like to avoid it, because in really big projects it doesn't save any time

Comment: And again, you just run `ng lint` and it gives you a full list of the files that have warnings/errors.

Comment: I can't run it because the node version needed to the deprecated application doesn't support Angular CLI

Comment: Then update it, because even your Node version doesn't support the CLI, there are high chances that it won't support the tool you ask for either. Also, `ng lint` is a shortcut, you can totally install tslint on your own and run `tslint` yourself. At some point, if you really want help, you gotta stop that bad faith man !

Comment: Node Sass could find binding for only the Node.js 6.x.. I know what you are saying, but the application is old and a lot of things are outdated in it, which happens in a company environment when you are working on big projects for years. I asked my question because if you have an Angular 4 project which is older, you would have the same problems on updating and you can't just update node to use some later supported commands. Unfortunately I can't use ng lint for this, but thanks for the recommendation, I will surely use it later!

Comment: Okay well good luck with your issue.

Comment: @trichetriche I successfully upgraded the version to 7.2+, if you would like to explain your point as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a cool tool known as [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/).

Select the app complexity, the versions you migrate from and to and you have a list to go.

[image: update.angular.io: params]

Here I selected advanced complexity and upgrade from 2 to 7. Here you get your `HttpModule` replaced with `HttpClientModule`

[image: update.angular.io: result]

Comment: Yea, it seems this will be the first thing to try. We already found it, it's just the same way I mentioned. We have to check every file manually with it. But thanks for the recommendation! It's a really great tool!